# WC format() Ошибка

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Есть такой код, который выводит время окончания действия купона:

```
$couponargs = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
   'post__in' => $couponarrayfinal,
   'orderby' => 'title',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'posts_per_page' => '-1');
$coupons = get_posts($couponargs);
   <div class="wt-mycoupons">
      <ul>
          <?php
             foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {

                $coupon_time = new WC_Coupon( $coupon->ID );

                echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon'>";
                 echo "<div class='coupon-info'>";
                  echo "<div class='title-coupon'>";
                   echo "$coupon->post_title";
                  echo "</div>";
                  echo "<div class='desc-coupon'>";
                   echo "$coupon->post_excerpt";
                  echo "</div>";
                 echo "</div>";
                 echo "<div class='coupon-expiry__time'>";
                  echo $coupon_time->get_date_expires();
                 echo "</div>";
                echo "</li>";
             }
           ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Дата таким способом выводится, но в формате 2019-10-30T21:00:00+00:00.
Когда меняю формат таким образом: `get_date_expires()->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' );`

Появляется ошибка и сайт сыпется. В чем проблема?

Comment: Какая ошибка? Какие версии php и WooCommerce?

Comment: Как посмотреть какая ошибка? Ну я вижу это по тому что сайт был таким: http://prntscr.com/m8x6wx, а после становится таким http://prntscr.com/m8x7ex. Версия PHP  7.1.18, версия WP 5.0.2 и версия WC 3.5.3

Comment: В консоле появляется вот такое: http://prntscr.com/m8xamx

Comment: Ну как вы можете увидеть php-ошибки в консоли? https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html

Comment: Понял, в чём дело, поправил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_date_expires()` может вернуть null, и тогда возникнет фатальная ошибка. Сделайте так:

```
$expires = $coupon_time->get_date_expires();
if ( $expires ) {
    echo $expires->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли, заработало!)